# Where does the padding-top&bottom come from in my css?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have this code for a simple 3-column layout (http://jsfiddle.net/7aC3U/)

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col col-1-3">
    <div class="module">
      <p>Col 1</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-3">
    <div class="module">
      <p>Col 2</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-1-3">
    <div class="module">
      <p>Col 3</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px; }
.col {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px; }
.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%; }
.module {
  background: white; }
```

Somehow the wrapper-div (red) has a padding-top and bottom, and I can't seem to figure out where this comes from. Can somebody help me?

Comment: its the default styling of the browser

Comment: hm, even if I set `padding: 0 0 0 20px;` it stays the same. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every browser reads the html and css codes differently. They have their own little changes they bring to the code. To avoid this you can use a css reset before the code.

But you can solve this easily by doing this:
In your case it is the automatic margin of the `<p>` element. Just write

```
p{
margin:0;
}
```

below the code and that will be enough

Comment: Thanks, that was it. But shouldn't the padding then extend only the "mod" div which is white? Why is the red wrapper affected by this?

Comment: As far as I remember browsers automatically put a margin of 25px on stuff like <p>. Headings <h1> also have margins.

Comment: Do you mean the "red" wrapper? 
The automatic padding forces the white mod div out. The white mod div, then pushes the red wrapper out with it. It is sad, but something we have to live with as programmers.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I meant the red wrapper. Thank you for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
* {padding:0;margin:0}
```

it reset all padding and margin in all tags to 0 and please dont use box-sizing there its not good practice according to me

Comment: Thanks, it works using `* {margin:0}`. What I find strange is that it doesn't work when I apply `margin:0` to the other divs (not using the `*` selector). Why is using box-sizing not a good practise in your opinion?

Comment: you can apply padding and margin to any tag it wont effect